# Scheduling a task using postDelayed after getting time delay between time picker and current time

Tags: android, android-handler, android-timepicker

I have written a piece of code in my fragment which will display a `Toast` message at a specific time selected by a user on a `Time Picker`. The time delay is calculated by subtracting the current time in milliseconds from the time picker time in milliseconds. 
However the toast message is not being displayed and I am not getting any errors either in the logcat. 
Here is the code snippet:

```
public class ManualControlsFragment extends Fragment {
    private TimePicker tp;
    private Calendar calendar;
    Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable scheduledTask;
    long pickedTimeInMillis=0;

   //some fragment methods

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tp = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.lightTimePickerStart);
        tp.setIs24HourView(true);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //get time picked in milliseconds
        tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                pickedTimeInMillis= calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            }
        });

        //Calendar instance to get current time
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        //get the difference to get the delay
        long timeDifference = pickedTimeInMillis - cal.getTimeInMillis();

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(scheduledTask, timeDifference);

        scheduledTask = new Runnable() {
            String text= "Bulb is now on";
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        return view;
    }
```

After reading the comments and an answer here, I edited the code to this:

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                String text= "Bulb is now on";
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 1 second
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, timeDifference);
        }
    });
```

However, this makes the toast display only when I launch the application(the time on the time picker when I launch it is at the current time which is why I suppose it then displays that toast). When I set a time on the time picker while application is running, the toast is not displayed.

Comment: Try `runOnUIThread()` and pass aplicationContext into your Toast instead of `getActivity()`

Comment: Why did you initialize the scheduledTask field *after* you use it in the postDelayed() method? Also, the postDelayed method will be called with a delay of 0 as the timeDifference that you calculate will be a negative value(due to pickedTimeInMillis not being initialized(defaults to 0) at the point of use as the user hasn't yet triggered the OnTimeChangedListener yet).

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks for pointing all that out. I'll use `runOnUIThread()` and also initialize `pickedTimeInMillis` to 0

Comment: @Skullper Thanks for your answer. I used `getActivity.getApplicationContext()`instead.

Comment: @Skullper I used `runOnUIThread()`(check my updated codes in the post). However, this makes the toast display only when I launch the application(the time on the time picker when I launch it is at the current time which is why I suppose it then displays that toast). When I set a time on the time picker while application is running, the toast is not displayed.

Comment: @Luksprog I used runOnUIThread() and initialized pickedTimeInMillis to 0(check my updated codes in the post). However, this makes the toast display only when I launch the application(the time on the time picker when I launch it is at the current time which is why I suppose it then displays that toast). When I set a time on the time picker while application is running, the toast is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment you need to change the order in your code to make it execute as you want.

First, initialize the scheduledTask **before** you use it in the Handler's postDelayed() method otherwise all you do is post a null Runnable. Your code should be:

```
scheduledTask = new Runnable() {
        String text= "Bulb is now on";
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(scheduledTask, timeDifference);
```

Secondly, the code below(inside of the onCreateView() method):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//get the difference to get the delay
long timeDifference = pickedTimeInMillis - cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

will trigger a Toast right away because pickedTimeInMillis will be **0** so the time difference will be negative, which will get rounded up to 0(so execute right away). If you want this, leave this part of the code otherwise remove it from onCreateView().

Thirdly, you need to post the Runnable  **as the user changes the time** and the OnTimeChangedListener listener gets called. So the code in the listener should be:

```
@Override
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            pickedTimeInMillis= calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            // at this point get the current time 
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            // now calculate the difference as the user actually selected a time
            long timeDifference = pickedTimeInMillis - cal.getTimeInMillis();
            // register the Runnable to run
            mHandler.postDelayed(scheduledTask, timeDifference);
        }
```

Also, runOnUiThread() is not needed because the Handler, as you declared it, will run on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However the toast appears after about 20 seconds after the set time. I need it to appear in real-time as it's for a real-time system. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @Tia I think that is happening because the Calendar instance that you use to register the time values selected by the user take in consideration the seconds of the current time, while the TimePicker only picks between hours and minutes. When you set the values selected by the user on the Calendar, set the seconds to be 0: *...calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)...*.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll check that once I am done fixing some other error as currently my app is crashing..

Comment: Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517417/app-crashing-with-com-google-gson-jsonsyntaxexception After I worked on the `Time Picker`, handler, my app has suddenly started crashing with that error even though I commented out that all the codes after it started to crash.

Comment: I just deleted the ques as the error has suddenly stopped being reproduced.

Comment: I have other threads running.. The handler seems to cause `Looper` issues and at times crashes the app or just disconnects my mob from Android Studio.. I'll use `runOnUiThread` instead

Comment: The codes however has a bug in it.. Even when I used `Runnable`(Currently I am using `Looper.getMainLooper())` though), the toast would be displayed very minute. Because I think the time picker registers each minute while I scroll down the picker to select a minute. Like suppose I have to set the time to 14:30 and currently it is 14:25 on the time picker, I have to scroll down the picker from the 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 and then finally to 30. I think this is why the time picker displays the toast at every minute.

Comment: @Tia To register only one time the Runnable, at the **start** of the onTimeChanged() method simply add the line *mHandler.removeCallbacks(scheduledTask)*. That line will remove any previous Runnable that you might set as you clicked the TimePicker's spinners.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I actually was in a bit of a hurry to fix it so I posted a ques on that and I got a similar ans to yours which suggested using `removeCallbacks()`

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520616/time-picker-performs-scheduled-task-every-minute-until-set-time-is-reached-inste?noredirect=1#comment86047019_49520616

Answer (score 0):

You are running the `Toast` on another thread, but you can only update the UI from the main thread. Try updating your code in `Runnable run()` to use the `runOnUiThread()` method, for example.

Comment: I used runOnUIThread() and initialized pickedTimeInMillis to 0(check my updated codes in the post). However, this makes the toast display only when I launch the application(the time on the time picker when I launch it is at the current time which is why I suppose it then displays that toast). When I set a time on the time picker while application is running, the toast is not displayed.